# Reusing PhoneApplicationPage instances

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, windows-phone-7.1

I'm developing a windows phone app, one of my pages use a panorama that loads a bunch of UIElements, taking a good share of memory.
Since every time I navigate to that view the page is created all over again, is there any way to reuse the page instance? Or there is any other way to ensure that the UIElements aren't created more than once?

**EDIT:**

The navigation process is the follows:

```
HomePage -> Secundary Page
Back
HomePage -> Secundary Page
Back
HomePage -> Secundary Page
etc.
```

What I want is that the secundary page instance to be reused after the first navigation.

Thanks

Comment: There may be a problem with the navigation flow of your application. Why are you navigating many times to the same page?

Comment: I've a list of items being presented on the home page, the user tapping on one it navigates to the page, then he can go back and tap on another item navigate back to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`PhoneApplicationPage`'s lifecycle is completely managed by the runtime, you cannot influence it in any way. If user goes back from the page, it will be re-created next time. See [this document](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff817008%28v=vs.105%29.aspx), "The OnNavigatedFrom Method" section.

In fact, if you absolutely want to keep secondary page in memory, you could override normal back button behavior on the secondary page, and instead of going *back* to main page, you'd go *forward* to the main page. Of course, you'll have to keep the backstack in order, to avoid side-effects mentioned in KooKiz's answer.

Note that it's still not guaranteed that secondary page will stay in memory, since it's up to garbage collector to decide. The more memory page consumes, the better candidate it is for GC.

Comment: If this answer has solved your problem, please consider accepting it, so that other people reading this will benefit from this knowledge as well.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is how you get page to the main page after navigating to a secondary page.

My guess is that, from the secondary page, you're calling:

```
NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Absolute));
```

This is wrong, for two reasons:

- As you noticed, you'll create a new instance of the page each time, and therefore use large amounts of memory
- To exit the application, the user will have to press back as many times as they navigated to the main page

Instead, since the main page is still is the navigation stack, just call `GoBack` from the secondary page to re-use the previous instance of the main page:

```
NavigationService.GoBack();
```

Comment: @DVD Oh, then I don't believe it's possible to re-use the instance of the secondary page. That said, memory shouldn't be a problem as the page is cleared when you go back to the main page. The only concern is the time needed to re-create the controls each time. You can also display the contents using a popup control in the main page rather than using a separate page, but it depends on how you're displaying the information.

Comment: Actually the mem grow up to >100mb before GC was called, on 256mb device it always crashed after a while. I end up to put all my xaml on a user control and handle its life cycle, now its stable on 40mbs everytime XD. Thanks for the help ;)

Comment: @DVD Sounds like a memory leak. Are you displaying large pictures?

Comment: only the one on the panorama background, but already fixed the large mem usage from the panorama bg by saving the (remote)image to the isolated storage.